# React native Ios app crashes on ios 12.1 or below

Tags: ios, react-native, crash, ios12, xcode10.1

We have a react native app which is getting crashed on launch in prod live store when installed on ios 12.1 or below. Though it works fine on ios 12.2 
I am not sure what could be the problem as it seems impossible.
Has anyone faced this issue?
I don't have ios 12.1 or below in simulator and also not able to download it gives  authorization error.